# Google People API get gender error in scopes.profile

Tags: android, google-api, google-people-api

first, i actually want to get gender from old way, but it says that already deprecated , and i get error at getGender(); it's not recognized

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
Intent Home=new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
            Home.putExtra("name",acct.getDisplayName());
            Home.putExtra("email", acct.getEmail());
            Home.putExtra("URL",acct.getPhotoUrl());
            Home.putExtra("URL",acct.getGender()); // cannot resolve method
            startActivity(Home);
```

and then i searched through here and get a bit surprised that i couldn't find many topic about this People API, the one popular answer though is from isabella chen :

```
    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

// On worker thread
GoogleAccountCredential credential =
         GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, Scopes.PROFILE);
credential.setSelectedAccount(
        new Account(googleSignInAccount.getEmail(), "com.google"));
People service = new People.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME /* whatever you like */) 
                .build();
// All the person details
Person meProfile = service.people().get("people/me").execute();
// e.g. Gender
List<Gender> genders = meProfile.getGenders();
String gender = null;
if (genders != null && genders.size() > 0) {
    gender = genders.get(0).getValue();
}
```

I try to reuse the code but i get error at the Scopes.PROFILES , it says wrong 2nd type argument...  , i don't understand.

here is my google code :

```
            //Initializing google signin option
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
                .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .build();


        gplus_button = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        gplus_button.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        gplus_button.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        //Initializing google api client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();
```

I will use whatever works, even the deprecated one, unfortunately i get error on both ways.

edit for clear question:

deprecated method error : Error in getGender();  , cannot resolve method

newer method : Error in Scopes.PROFILE  , red underline in android studio says wrong 2nd type argument. found 'java.lang.String' required type 'java.util.Collection'

Comment: what are your errors?

Comment: for old method, "cannot resolve method", and in the new method, its said wrong type 2nd argument (the Scopes.PROFILE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i found the solution.

I need to use collection/array for the Scopes.PROFILE.

```
Collection<String> scopes = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(Scopes.PROFILE));
GoogleAccountCredential credential = 
                    GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, scopes);
```

now it worked. thx

Comment: hey bro, one question. WHy a list of genders?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are asking two scopes? Delete the `PLUS_LOGIN` scope line, which you dont need. The `PROFILE` scope gives you more information. You can simply use only this. OR you can ask more than one scope in the same line like,

```
(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN), new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
```

Comment: you're right, its more because i've tried so many example i found on the internet. however, that doesn't really answer to my question right now.